# Stream bytes into an asp.net website from Flash

Tags: asp.net, flash

I want to stream a webcam from Flash into an asp.net website? (RTMP)

Is it possible to send a stream bytes from a Flash application on users browser directly to some sort of ASP.Net web service?

Comment: Are you looking something similar to this? [RTMP Data Push from .NET to Flex](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_RTMP_Data_Push_from__NET_to_Flex-16983.html)

Comment: thanks, I believe this product is not into an asp.net website but in and out of a .net windows application.